# Creating a function that returns the URL of an HTML hyperlink

Tags: python, html, hyperlink

My function has to return the URL of an HTML hyperlink in the format `<a href="URL">TEXT</a>`

So, For example if the hyperlink is `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google homepage</a>`. If I input that in my function `url(x)`, I would get back `www.google.com`. I know I have to splice out that part of the string but what would be a good start for this code?
I am using python 3.4.1

Comment: Are you dealing with the hyperlink as a string or as an element?  Are you passing in a reference to the <a> tag?  i.e. document.findElementByTagName()?  Is it a jQuery object?

Comment: its dealing with the hyperlink as a string

Comment: So you'll be using: `url('<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>')`?

Comment: correct, I would put that in my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed your tags from javascript to python...

Looks like you're going to want a regex.

```
import re

def url(x) :
    match = re.search(r"href=\"(.*)\"", x)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    else:
        return ""


print url('<a href="asdf">asdfasdf</a>')
```

http://python.codepad.org/Jgc3STrq

Comment: is there a way I could do this without regex? we have not learned that yet.

Comment: If you know the format of the string, i.e. <a href="..."> -- you can find the position of the substring href=  using python's String.find method, then you can find the first occurrence of " and the second occurrence of " after the href=, then you can extract the characters between the two.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getUrl(elem) {
    return elem.href;
}
var string = getUrl(document.getElementById('aTagID'));
```

This will not remove the 'http://' but you can slice the resultant string if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can split input if it's Url, and concatinate strings to make url from input if it's not url. All you need is to determine input. It can depend from Url.